# Memory Efficiency in Java

Tags: java, optimization, memory, jvm

With regard to Memory usage and variable instantiation which is better or is there no difference :

This

```
for(int i = 0; i < someValue; i++)
{
    Obj foo = new Obj();
    Use foo.....
}
```

As opposed to:

```
Obj foo;

for(int i = 0; i < someValue; i++)
{
    foo = new Obj();
    Use foo.....
}
```

Comment: The first version is better, because it potentially reduces the lifetime of the object.

Comment: No difference in terms of memory usage. Stop giving importance to such tiny details and focus on the bigger picture!

Comment: Don't try to do the job of the compiler.

Comment: @Cicada: this is a totally legitimate question

Comment: I can't imagine how much time I wasted on urban legends like this when I was learning to program, SO does a great job.

Comment: @nosid Absolutely not true. Even assuming javac did generate different bytecode, the JIT will do liveness analysis.

Comment: @Voo "Absolutely not true" is a bit over the top. nosid said "potentially reduces" and that much is true. Not all VM implementations do the analysis, and those that do, don't do it for all code, all the time.

Comment: @Marko Which modern JVM doesn't do liveness analysis? I mean it's quite the simple optimization and is basically a byproduct of other runs. Yes for interpreted code it isn't run, but the point is the *lifetime* of an object doesn't purely depend on its scope according to the JLS.

Comment: @Marko True. I could be nitpicking that the time when it is actually collected doesn't have to coincide with the time it is dead according to the JLS, but that'd be nitpicking - I get your point ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference. Any potential difference in terms of memory usage would be optimized by the compiler.

If you compile (using `javap -c`) the two examples and compare the bytecode, you'll find that the bytecode is the same. Of course, this depends on the JVM version. But since this example is so trivial, it's probably safe to assume that neither is more memory efficient than the other.

---

### Example 1:

Code:

```
public class example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Object a = new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

Bytecode:

```
public class example1 extends java.lang.Object{
public example1();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   bipush  10
   5:   if_icmpge       22
   8:   new     #2; //class java/lang/Object
   11:  dup
   12:  invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   15:  astore_2
   16:  iinc    1, 1
   19:  goto    2
   22:  return
}
```

---

### Example 2:

Code:

```
public class example2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object a;
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            a = new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

Bytecode:

```
public class example2 extends java.lang.Object{
public example2();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_2
   2:   iload_2
   3:   bipush  10
   5:   if_icmpge       22
   8:   new     #2; //class java/lang/Object
   11:  dup
   12:  invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   15:  astore_1
   16:  iinc    2, 1
   19:  goto    2
   22:  return
}
```

Comment: Now This was quick thinking - Kudos

Comment: i would prefer the second one (which declares the variable outside of the loop) , so that for debugging i would see the current value of the variable and that it won't become invisible  and visible on each loop iteration.

Comment: Joshua Bloch (author of [*Effective Java*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)) would argue otherwise, as described in **Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables**. :)

Answer (score 6):

With modern JVM both will work the same, also compiler optimization will take make both of them same.

Ignoring compiler optimization and modern JVM, 1st approach is better.

Comment: You compared the 2 scenarios wrongly. By the way, first approach is more readable (no unnecessary object scope).

Answer (score 5):

The first example makes most sense in terms of object scope, but both should be as memory efficient as the other.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between your examples, as is pointed out in other answers. But the interestiong question is: if your example is slow, what should you do?

If you want to reduce time spent in allocations/garbage collections in a really performance critical section, consider re-using objects instead of allocating new objects on each iteration.

```
foo = new Obj();
for(int i = 0; i < someValue; i++)
{
    foo.init(i);
    Use foo.....
}
```

From [java performance tuning](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html) (an old book, but the same holds true in modern jvm:s and in the .NET clr)

> ... objects are expensive to create. Where
>   it is reasonable to reuse the same object, you should do so. You need
>   to be aware of when not to call new. One fairly obvious situation is
>   when you have already used an object and can discard it before you are
>   about to create another object of the same class. You should look at
>   the object and consider whether it is possible to reset the fields and
>   then reuse the object, rather than throw it away and create another.
>   This can be particularly important for objects that are constantly
>   used and discarded

Comment: Reusing objects leads to rarer, but therefore extremely expensive GC runs - collecting young objects is dirt cheap. Often enough that's actually contraproductive on modern JVMs (the Hotspot guys don't generally recommend it afaik)

Comment: In the above example, why would the collection be more expensive? I'm more accustomed to the CLR, where I'm often limited by allocations, especially since in the default GC mode you cannot allocate on one thread if a GC was triggered by another.

Comment: You probably want to read up on generational GCs. Yes the CLR is still quite bad wrt parallel GC algorithms, but the same principle applies there as well: Lots of extremely short, cheap young gen GCs are better than a handful of extremely expensive old gen GCs. Young objects that die young are what modern JVMs are expected to optimize most.

Comment: I am familiar with generational gc:s and the different costs. What I'm trying to say is that there are cases when you cannot afford to even allocate ONE gen0 object inside each iteration, regardless of how cheap it may feel. My example is typically valid for scenarios with many threads that would allocate up to the Gen0 limit quickly if they were allowed to allocate in each iteration. Look at how the .NET Workstation GC handles that for example: once the GC is triggered, ALL threads pause for the GC. Serializing execution like that is much more expensive than the GC and allocation itself.

Comment: I should add: allocating an object is still more expensive than NOT allocating an object. While it is true that allocating older generations is more expensive: is it better to be GC:ing one single object in a higher generation after 100k iterations, or doing 100 Gen0 GC:s with 1000 objects each if you have a 100k iteration loop? There are no simple answers here. Depends on the GC implementation and the amounts allocated. Just profile the code and do what you need. Re-using objects is a last resort to be used only if you get a  large performandce benefit from it.

Comment: Yeah Java GC algorithms are a good bit better than the CLR ones in general. But the thing is: The cost of a young GC is proportional to the number of *live* objects. Assuming we're doing some real work, we'll get young GCs anyhow and removing the dead objects in those is free. Which means in the worst case we get maybe one or two more young GCs (in the best case the behavior doesn't change at all) but avoid adding to the dearly expensive old gen GC. Obviously that doesn't apply to large objects that aren't allocated in eden to begin with.

Comment: Again, talking about allocation mainly in the typical case, not GC. Also: like I said, just profile the code and don't optimize unless there are real performance benefits.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler optimization will make both of them same. I prefer the first approach better, however, if you were to ignore the compiler optimization. It is more to the point and even Joshua Bloch suggests to do so in Effective Java (a great read).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should optimize this for you. I would prefer the first over the second as it is more readable. Letting `Object foo` have a larger scope could be a source of confusion.